# Removing versions not following the format from an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, rubygems

I have a sorted array of tagged versions of my repo which looks as per below:

```
["0.1.0", "0.2.0", "0.3.0", "0.4.0", "0.4.1", "0.5.0", "0.6.0", "0.7.0", "1.0.0", "1.1.0", "1.1.1", "1.2.0", "1.3.0", "1.3.0-something", "1.4.0", "1.4.1", "1.4.1-some-something", "1.4.2", "1.4.2-something", "1.5.0", "1.5.1", "1.5.1-something", "1.6.0", "1.6.0-some-something", "6-01-2014-something-0.1-Release", "7-28-2014-something-0.2-Release", "something-0.2-MASTER", "something-3-TP"]
```

In this array the last 4 objects are clearly not following the versioning format and they were just made as an example. Is there a way I can remove them from the array?

I actually want the latest tagged version for which I sort list of all the tagged versions and then get the last one. Is there a gem or some other way to get the latest tagged version of a repo?

Comment: The fact that you're manipulating Git tag names is only incidental to the question. Removing [tag:git] and [tag:gitub-api] tags...

Comment: Don't you think you could have used a little smaller sample array? Like maybe two elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expression and [`Array#keep_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-keep_if) to remove non-version strings:

```
versions = [
  "0.1.0", "0.2.0", "0.3.0", "0.4.0", "0.4.1", "0.5.0", "0.6.0", "0.7.0",
  "1.0.0", "1.1.0", "1.1.1", "1.2.0", "1.3.0", "1.3.0-something", "1.4.0",
  "1.4.1", "1.4.1-some-something", "1.4.2", "1.4.2-something", "1.5.0",
  "1.5.1", "1.5.1-something", "1.6.0", "1.6.0-some-something",
  "6-01-2014-something-0.1-Release", "7-28-2014-something-0.2-Release",
  "something-0.2-MASTER", "something-3-TP"
]
versions.keep_if { |v| v =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+/ }
# => ["0.1.0",
#     "0.2.0",
#     "0.3.0",
#     "0.4.0",
#     ...
#     "1.5.1-something",
#     "1.6.0",
#     "1.6.0-some-something"]
```

To get the last version only, use [`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-select), then [`Array#last`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-last) or `...[-1]`:

```
versions.select { |v| v =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+/ }.last
# => "1.6.0-some-something"
```

Comment: versions.select and the using .last gives me "something-3-TP" I think versions.keep_if and then .last should give me the right stuff.

Comment: @tech_human, It's strange. Are you sure? The return value of the `select` should be same with `keep_if` except that `keep_if` manipulate the array in-place while `select` does not.

Comment: yes I did versions.select { |v| v =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+/ }.last and it returned me "something-3-TP"

Comment: No wait I take it back... I got the right version with select

Comment: Yes it works with select. BTW wasn't aware about this "asciinema.org". Looks useful to me. Thanks falsetru! :)